# Iterate over digits of number

Tags: python, string, for-loop

I have a string input, such as `100124`. I want to evaluate each digit of the string as an integer, so I do:

```
for c in string:
    c = int(c)
    # do stuff with c
```

Is there a syntactically better way to do this? I tried doing `string = int(string)` before the loop, but a number isn't iterable.

Comment: You need to show more code lines of context so we know what you're ultimately trying to do.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You could [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) the string to `int`:

```
for c in map(int, string):
    # do stuff with c
```

Demo:

```
>>> for c in map(int, '100124'):
...     c
...
1
0
0
1
2
4
>>>
```

Comment: Indeed. This is Prime.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a list comprehension that return a generator :

```
>>> [int(i) for i in s]
[1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 4]
>>> for digit in [int(i) for i in s] :
...    # do stuff with digit
```

or [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) function :

```
>>> map(int,s)
[1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 4]
```